# Centralizar a legenda de uma imagem figcaption

Tags: html, css3

Não consigo centralizar a legenda da imagem em relação a imagem. Já tentei com text-align: center; mas não deu certo. Segue o código:

```
<figure class="foto-legenda1">
    <img src="media/airlines-arena.jpg" class="image1"/>
    <figcaption>
        <p><i> Miami Heat in a game opening </i></p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Pode fornecer o CSS usado também?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os elementos na tag `figcaption` não são propriamente alinhados consoante a posição da imagem na tag *img*, são alinhados consoante a a tag *figure*, ou seja, quando você define uma propriedade css, `text-align="center"`, o que fazes é alinhar o texto ao centro de *figure* e não de *img*.

Algo que podes fazer para corrigir isto, é definir um tamanho para a tag *figure*, e em seguida, atribuir uma propriedade `width` ao css de *img* com *100%* do valor, que será igual ao tamanho total desse container *(`figure`)*. Assim o texto ficará sempre alinhado ao centro da imagem, e do próprio container.

```
figure {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
figure img {
    width:100%;     
}
figcaption p, i {
    text-align:center;  
}
```

> NOTA: **figcaption p, i** repara na vírgula entre os 2 elementos (p, i), sem ela a referência seria ao elemento `i` dentro do elemento (`p`), com a vírgula a propriedade aplicada, seria para o elemento `p` e o elemento `i` dentro da tag *figcaption*.

Answer (score 0):

Basta atribuir um display block no i:

```
figcaption p i {
  display: block;
  text-align: center
}
```